# Check for amount of new items between two lists

Tags: excel-formula

I have a list of groceries. Between Day 1 and 2, I want to know how many new items I gained or lost between the days.

I want a function that can tell me the amount of Food items gained. In this case it would be 2 (Banana and Chicken). I also need it to tell me how many lost, in this case 1 (Oreo).

Thanks!

[image: Excel Link]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gain:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((COUNTIFS(B:B,B2:B15,A:A,A2:A15-1)=0)*(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2:A15-1)>0))/(COUNTIFS(B:B,B2:B15,A:A,A2:A15)))
```

Loss:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((COUNTIFS(B:B,B2:B15,A:A,A2:A15+1)=0)*(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2:A15+1)>0))/(COUNTIFS(B:B,B2:B15,A:A,A2:A15)))
```

[image]